# Adding array to a model file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have the following array in my view file (which works):

```
<?php
$images = array(img("slideshow/demo1.png", "one"),img("slideshow/demo2.png", "two"),img("slideshow/demo4.png", "three"));

$captions = array("first image", "second image", "third image");
foreach (array_combine($images, $captions) as $image => $caption ) {
echo "<li>", $image, "<div class=\"orbit-caption\">",$caption,"</div></li>";
}
?>
```

However I wish to use the same foreach in a slideshow file across multiple pages with different images displaying so i thought the simplest way would be to create a model page for each page that required different data and having the images and captions in an array as above. I have tried searching how to do this but all the solutions I have found relate to being in a database which is unfortunately not an option.

Also I would like to code it so that if there is not image caption the caption code does not run ie:

```
"<div class=\"orbit-caption\">",$caption,"</div>
```

The options I have tried either I get a blank semi transparent box ie it puts down:

```
<div class="orbit-caption"></div>
```

Or I getting nothing if I have a caption or not.

I understand a small amount of php but am more of a designer and am fairly new to MVC so will not be offended if anyone has a solution in an idiots guide :) just trying to learn. If anyone has a better solution then please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper in `application/helpers` folder and name it `slideshow_helper.php`, Now, in `slideshow_helper.php` write :

```
<?php
function get_image_array(){
    $images = array(img("slideshow/demo1.png", "one"),img("slideshow/demo2.png", "two"),img("slideshow/demo4.png", "three"));
    $captions = array("first image", "second image", "third image");
    return array_combine($images, $captions);
}
?>
```

In your **controller function** from where you load the `view for slideshow page`, write:

```
<?php
$data   = array();
$this->load->helper('slideshow');
$data['slideshow'] = get_image_array();        #will return the image array from the helper
$this->load->view('view', $data);              #load the image array in the view
?>
```

In your **View**:

```
<?php
foreach ($image as $imageSrc => $caption ) {
    if($caption != ""){
        echo "<li>", $imageSrc, "<div class=\"orbit-caption\">",$caption,"</div></li>";    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If I wanted different images/captions on each page though what would I call or need to add as should have said the slideshow would be included into the other view pages was going to use include.

Comment: If you are not going to use database then I would suggest to make different `function(s)` for each of your view and call the required functions from your controller as done above.

Comment: Ok finally had a chance to sit down and actually try this and it does not work :(

Comment: changed $data['slideshow']; to $data['image']; now works thanks saved a lot of head scratching :)